# Unable to update saved data in core data

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I had a core data problem where I am unable to update the saved data in table view but I am able to pass the saved data to text fields of destination view controller but unable to update it and pass it to previous view controller. I am able to edit in text fields but unable to update the content in previous table view controller in which the data was saved previously.

```
    func Plus(sender: AnyObject) {



        if store == nil
        {
            //get the description of the entity
            let storeDescription = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Store",inManagedObjectContext: appdelegate.managedObjectContext)

            //we create managed object to be inserted to core data
            let store = EventsandnotesStore(entity : storeDescription!,insertIntoManagedObjectContext:appdelegate.managedObjectContext)
            store.sName = name.text
            store.sDescription = desc.text

            let img = UIImage(named: "image.jpg")
            let imgData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(img!,1)
            store.sImage = imgData
            do {
                try appdelegate.managedObjectContext.save()
                self.navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)
            } catch let error as NSError  {
                print("Could not save \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
            }
        }
```

Comment: The Core Data save that you are showing isn’t the code responsible for showing the data in your view controller. You should show that code.

Comment: I dont know how to update the edited text field content into core data. Below I had given the

Comment: I had given the code for passing the data to next view controller.                                                               override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    
        if segue.identifier == "show"
        {
            let v = segue.destinationViewController as! ViewController
            let indexpath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow!
            let row = indexpath.row
            v.store = stores[row]
        }
Please tell me the code for updating the content in core data. I am new to swift and app development.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do one of two things

Implement a delegate pattern to pass the updated info back to your original view controller. Then you can update the data source for your tableView manually.

Or you could use an [NSFetchedResultsController](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreData/Reference/NSFetchedResultsController_Class/) as the dataSource for your tableView and implement its [delegate](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreData/Reference/NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate) functions. This enables you to notify your tableView that core data has updated.

I recommend the latter, it'll be a bit more work to setup but makes life much easier.

Comment: I finally got the data updated, I messed up with the delegates.